# Open FTP only on certain IP address

Tags: networking, ufw, vsftpd

on a remote machine there are two network interfaces.

- eth0: 10.10.0.15  (VLAN)
- eth1:  33.33.22.22  (Public IP)

I want the VSFTPD to only receive and entertain requests from the public IP and localhost and not from the VLAN or any machines on VLAN. I added the following rules t the UFW:

```
ufw allow proto tcp from 33.33.22.22 to any port 20:21
```

this is for passive FTP

```
ufw allow proto tcp from 33.33.22.22 to any port 40000:40100
```

however with this setting the FileZilla is stuck

```
Connecting to 33.33.22.22
Connection established, waiting for welcomemessage...
Initializing TLS
verifying certificate
Logged in
Retrieving directory listing...
```

and then it is stuck for few seconds and then retries.

with this setting

```
ufw allow proto tcp from any to any port 40000:40100
```

it starts working but then connections from other machines on VLAN is also possible.
how can I achieve the desired results or that's not possible?

Comment: `from` will restrict the source IP, not the target. Try `allow in on eth1` or maybe `to 33.33.22.22`.

Comment: While you could use a firewall to stop incoming requests, the easier thing would be to configure `vsftpd` to just listen on one address. Use `listen_address=33.33.22.22 ` in `vsftpd.conf`